# handling errors in return type File for actions assigned to img src

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have an MVC project using C# and ASP.net, In my ASP page, I have an HTML img tag with src attribute assigned to a controller action. How do I handle exceptions thrown from there?

In my controller, the return type of the action method is ActionResult and I'm returning a file

```
try {
    ....
    return File(img, "image/jpeg");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    ViewBag.Error = e.message; <-- how do I display this in my asp page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use log4net library for display error into the view side.
you can see the basic example for the log4net is follow

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/513202/Simplest-Implementation-of-log-net

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example on how to display it in the view side? Thank you!

Comment: try
   {
    ......... 
       return File(img, "image/jpeg");                                                       } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.Error("xxxxxxxx", e);
      
   }